# Why we can't access to a protected base class member using the pointer to derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I've written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
protected:
    void foo()
    {
        printf("class A\n");
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    void bar()
    {
        printf("class B\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    B *b= new B();
    b->foo();
}
```

And when I'm compiling it I've an error

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:7: error: ‘void A::foo()’ is protected
test.cpp:23:9: error: within this context
```

But in the N3797 working draft said that

> **protected**; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared, by classes derived from
>   that class, and by their friends

and

> if a class is declared to be a base class (Clause 10) for another
>   class using the public access specifier, the public members of the
>   base class are accessible as public members of the derived class and
>   protected members of the base class are accessible as protected
>   members of the derived class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967352/why-cant-i-access-a-protected-member-from-an-instance-of-a-derived-class?rq=1

Comment: I don't understand the question. `main` is neither a member of `B`, nor a friend of it, so why would it get access to any non-public member of it?

Answer (score 4):

Your code, which tries to call `b->foo()`, is:

- not a member of `A`
- not a friend of `A`
- not a member of `B` (the only derived type)
- not a friend of `B`

so by the passage you quote, it cannot use the name `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply: You are trying to access the protected member from *outside* your class hierarchy. The following would work:

```
class B : public A
{
    void bar() // bar is "inside" your class hierarchy
    {
        foo(); // compiles
        printf("class B\n");
    }
};
```

But this not:

```
// some code, e.g. in main
b->foo(); // error - "outside" of the class
```

See [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564668/1451714) for a formal explanation.

---

**Note**: Your class B could make the `protected` member `public`, like this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    // This adds a public foo to B, which invokes the protected foo from A
    void foo()
    {
        A::foo(); 
    }
};
```

With that, your example would work, as long as you're using a `B` pointer/instance/reference.

Answer (score 0):

`B`, not `main`, can access `A`'s members.

Options:

1. Make `foo()` public, instead of protected
2. Have a public method within `B` that calls `foo()` and call that.

Answer (score 0):

From  `main` you can just access `public members of B` defined in B or inherited from A.